# Write exponent as iterative sums.

Tags: summation, exponentiation, products

If we let $z=xy$, we have:
$$z=\sum_{i=1}^{y}x$$
So multiplication can be written as iterative sum. Likewise, if we have $z=x^y$, then we can write:
$$z=\prod_{i=1}^{y}x$$
But how to write the exponent in sum form instead of product form?

I tried to experiment by writing for example $5^2=(5+5+5+5+5), 2^4=((2+2)+(2+2))+((2+2)+(2+2))$, but I came up with **nothing**.

**Edit:** From the conversation in the comments, you can write exponent as nested summations:

$$z=\sum_{i=1}^{x}\sum_{j=1}^{x}\sum_{k=1}^{x}\dots\text{(y times)}\dots  x$$

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a recursive formula? Otherwise some potentially involved sums would comprise a general form.

Comment: Whatever uses sums only, I'd be happy with.

Comment: Applying both your observations at the same time, consider $z=x^y = x^1 x^{y-1} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{x^{y-1}} x$ which could be swapped around if you don't like the "large" upper index, it could also be $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{x} x^{y-1}$

Comment: The summation itself uses exponentation, so it isn't the best that can be done.

Comment: What about nested sums? Such as if $z = x^y$, then you could iterate until you've hit a desired number of inner summations: $z = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{x} x^{y-1} = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{x} \left( \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{x} x^{y-2} \right) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{x} \left( \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{x} \left( \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{x} x^{y-3} \right) \right)$

Comment: That is closer to the solution, I actually came up with that myself, but is there a better notation for recursive summations? For example if I had to raise x to 77th power, I would have to nest the summations 77 times. Generally if I want to raise to yth powerI would have to nest summations y times. Sounds like a solution, but how to write that in a compact notation?

Comment: Well coming up with that is certainly not **nothing** like your original post suggested! But remember that recursive functions aren't explicitly iterative, which is in your question title.

Comment: I meant that I came up with this a minute ago. EDIT: I guess no one ever came up with a notation that would be able to represent x-nested summations. Interesting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?:

Let $z = x^y$. This will work for $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$.

$$
z = x^y \\ = \sum\limits_{i_1 = 1}^{x} x^{y-1} \\= \sum\limits_{i_1 = 1}^{x} \left( \sum\limits_{i_2 = 1}^{x} x^{y-2} \right) \\ = \sum\limits_{i_1 = 1}^{x} \left( \sum\limits_{i_2 = 1}^{x} \left( \sum\limits_{i_3 = 1}^{x} x^{y-3} \right) \right) \\ = \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i_1 = 1}^{x} \left( \sum\limits_{i_2 = 1}^{x} \left( \sum\limits_{i_3 = 1}^{x} \left( \cdots \left( \sum\limits_{i_y = 1}^{x} 1 \right) \right)  \right) \right)}_{y \text{ times}}
$$

Comment: Well, I realized that no one in the history ever thought of a compact notation that tells how many times something is nested, so basically your answer is possibly *the* answer.

Comment: So now you see the *power* of the notation for exponents! [pun intended]